# cannot find name 'require' when import { by } from 'protractor' is missing

Tags: angular, protractor

In following Angular Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
   })
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  version: string = require( '../../../../package.json').version;
  env: string = environment.env;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {      
  }

 }
```

When i build the solution i get following error

```
src/app/components/test/test.component.ts(12,21): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.
```

Strange thing is that when i add following import the issue is solved but i have no clue why?

```
import { by } from 'protractor';
```

Comment: Why are you using `require`? It's not supported in Angular. (That's NodeJS)

Comment: The application version is stored in the package.json file and we need to display this in the application

Comment: Your title says Protractor is missing. It might be installed as a devDependency. Also, this question does not appear to be a Protractor question but more of a import vs require question. Could you change the title and tag? Thanks!